# Gaps and Islands ? Or Not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
;with data as (
select '508325'  as [customer], 'G61' as [demo_given],
        cast('2015-1-1' as date) as [date_of_demo]
union all select '508325', 'G61', cast('2015-3-1' as date) 
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-3-15' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-3-16' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-3-17' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-6-1' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-8-1' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-9-1' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-9-1' as date)
union all select '508325', 'G61',cast('2015-12-1' as date)
)
```

Per customer there may be only 3 demos given in a 4 month period.
The first period starts counting at the first demo given and ends 4 months later.

If the number of demos in that period exceeds 3 I need the dates of the demos 4 and later in that 4 month period.
(that would be `2015-3-16` and `2015-3-17` in this example)

The next period starts at the date of the first demo given after the first four months. So I need to count the number of demos in the period `2015-6-1` up until `2015-9-30` and return the dates of the eventual 'surplus' demos given in that period.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used multiple step CTE for readability, but you can combine it if you want:

- `tally` - simple number table you can use any method you want (recursive cte, dummy table, table function,...)
- `min_date_per_customer` -  get first date of demo per customer
- `date_ranges` - generate ranges adding 4 month to min_date
- `final` - join `data` to `date_ranges`, generate row number
- `main query` - filter  out demos that are 4th, 5th, 6th, ... in specific period

Code:

```
WITH tally(N) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM sys.all_columns a CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns b
), min_date_per_customer AS (
  SELECT customer, MIN(date_of_demo) AS min_date
  FROM #data
  GROUP BY customer
), date_ranges AS (
  SELECT t.N, mdpc.customer
      ,[date_start] = DATEADD(m, 4 * (t.N - 1), min_date)
      ,[date_end]   = DATEADD(m, 4 *t.N, min_date)
  FROM min_date_per_customer mdpc
  CROSS JOIN tally t
  WHERE t.N < 100 -- you can generate as many period as you wish
), final AS (
  SELECT d.customer
       ,d.demo_given
       ,d.date_of_demo
       ,dr.N
       ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dr.customer, dr.N ORDER BY date_of_demo)
  FROM #data d
  JOIN date_ranges dr
    ON d.[date_of_demo] >= dr.date_start
   AND d.[date_of_demo] <= dr.date_end
   AND d.customer = dr.customer
)
SELECT *
FROM final
WHERE rn > 3
ORDER BY customer, date_of_demo;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382853)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══╦═════╗
║ customer ║ demo_given ║    date_of_demo     ║ N ║ rn  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══╬═════╣
║   508325 ║ G61        ║ 2015-03-16 00:00:00 ║ 1 ║   4 ║
║   508325 ║ G61        ║ 2015-03-17 00:00:00 ║ 1 ║   5 ║
║   508325 ║ G61        ║ 2015-09-01 00:00:00 ║ 2 ║   4 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══╩═════╝
```